# Matrix Permutations with Contraint

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, permutation

I have the following matrix:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

I'd like to randomly permute the columns, with the constraint that every four numbers in the second row should contain some form of

```
0 0 1 2
```

e.g. Columns 1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16, 17:20, 21:24 in the example below each contain the numbers 0 0 1 2.

```
0 1 0 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 2 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 2
```

Every column in the permuted matrix should have a corresponding one in the first matrix. In other words, nothing should be altered within a column.

I can't seem to think of an intuitive solution to this - Is there another way of coming up with some form of the initial matrix that both satisfies the constraint and retains the integrity of the columns? Each column represents conditions in an experiment, which is why I'd like them to be balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [rejection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling): keep trying random permutations, chosen equiprobably, until one satisfies the requirement. This guarantees that all valid permutations have the same probability of being picked.

```
A = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
      0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2
      0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ]; % data matrix
required = [0 0 1 2]; % restriction
row = 2; % row to which the resitriction applies

sorted_req = sort(required(:)); % sort required values
done = false; % initiallize
while ~done
    result = A(:, randperm(size(A,2))); % random permutation of columns of A
    test = sort(reshape(result(row,:), numel(required), []), 1); % reshape row
        % into blocks, each block in a column; and sort each block
    done = all(all(bsxfun(@eq, test, sorted_req))); % test if valid
end
```

Here's an example result:

```
result =
     2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2
     2 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 0 1 0
     2 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the permutations directly in the following manner:  First, permute all columns with `0` in the second row among themselves, then all `1`s among themselves, and finally all `2`s among themselves.  This ensures that, for example, any two `0` columns are equally likely to be the first two columns in the resulting permutation of `A`.
The second step is to permute all columns in blocks of 4: permute columns 1-4 randomly, permute columns 5-8 randomly, etc.  Once you do this, you have a matrix that maintains the (0 0 1 2) pattern for every block of 4 columns, but each set of (0 0 1 2) is equally likely to be in any given block of 4, and the (0 0 1 2) are equally likely to be in any order.

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]; 

%% Find the indices of the zeros and generate a random permutation with that size
zeroes = find(A(2,:)==0);
perm0 = zeroes(randperm(length(zeroes)));

%% Find the indices of the ones and generate a random permutation with that size
wons = find(A(2,:) == 1);
perm1 = wons(randperm(length(wons)));
%% NOTE: the spelling of `zeroes` and `wons` is to prevent overwriting 
%% the MATLAB builtin functions `zeros` and `ones`    

%% Find the indices of the twos and generate a random permutation with that size
twos = find(A(2,:) == 2);
perm2 = twos(randperm(length(twos)));

%% permute the zeros among themselves, the ones among themselves and the twos among themselves
A(:,zeroes) = A(:,perm0);
A(:,wons) = A(:,perm1);
A(:,twos) = A(:,perm2);

%% finally, permute each block of 4 columns, so that the (0 0 1 2) pattern is preserved, but each column still has an
%% equi-probable chance of being in any position
for i = 1:size(A,2)/4
    perm = randperm(4) + 4*i-4;
    A(:, 4*i-3:4*i) = A(:,perm);
end
```

Example result:

```
A =
  Columns 1 through 15
     1     1     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     1     2     2     1     2
     0     0     2     1     0     2     0     1     0     2     1     0     1     2     0
     0     1     2     2     2     0     1     1     1     1     2     0     0     2     0
  Columns 16 through 24
     2     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     1
     0     2     0     0     1     0     0     1     2
     1     1     2     2     0     0     2     1     0
```

I was able to generate 100000 constrained permutations of `A` in about 9.32 seconds running MATLAB 2016a, to give you an idea of how long this code takes.  There are certainly ways to optimize the permutation selection so you don't have to make quite so many random draws, but I always prefer the simple, straightforward approach until it proves insufficient.